# 7zip command line - extract all files in a folder except *.exe

Tags: 7-zip

I am using the command:

```
7z.exe x -y -o<dir> <archive dir> * -aoa -r
```

to extract all archives that are located in the archive directory.

I am running into a problem where exe files that are packaged end up getting extracted as well.

Is there a way to extract all files within a directory but exclude *.exe files?

I tried the -x flag (-x!*.exe and -xr!*.exe), but they exclude extracting *.exe from within the rar and zip archives.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what files to extract from inside the `<archive>` folder. If you want to only extract files from `.zip` files, you should specify `<archive>\*.zip`.

```
7z.exe x -y -o<dir> <archive dir>\*.zip * -aoa -r
```

Comment: Or if you change to `dir` first, you can omit that and run just `7z.exe x -y <archive dir>\*.zip * -aoa -r`.